# using multiple for-loops to call method

Tags: python

```
def func1(x,y,z):
  return (2^x + 3*y) / z


f1Ans = [func1(x,y,z) x for x in range (3,7), y for y in range(4,8), z for z in range(5,9)
```

is there any way that I can call the method on top using for-loops for the 3 parameters needed like how I intended on the bottom? If i try doing it like that it produces errors.

Comment: `[func1(x,y,z) for x in range (3,7) for y in range(4,8) for z in range(5,9)]`

Comment: Ah thanks so much! I was doing for x in x range(3,7) and it was producing errors.